# Can we define Big $O$ using less than, if $f(n)$ and $g(n)$ are always above zero?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

Can we say that $f(x)$ is $O(g(x))$ if there are constants $C$ and $k$ such that

$$f(x) < Cg(x)$$

whenever $x>k$.

If $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are always above zero?

I am pretty sure but I have never seen it defined like that anywhere.

Because simply if we can find $f(x) \leq Cg(x)$ it necessarily follows that $f(x) < (C+1)g(x)$ so we can can choose $C+1$ to be our constant.

Comment: The whole point of big-oh notation is that it "hides the constants." Asserting that "$f$ is $O(g)$" is equivalent to asserting "$f$ is $O(\frac{1}{2}g)$" and "$f$ is $O(2017g)$."

Comment: Yes, it's pretty common to omit the absolute values when dealing with the run times of algorithms, which are never negative.

Comment: @symplectomorphic I know that but I mean why do we need to define big O using <= or equal when < is enough if f(x) and g(x) are always greater than 0 at x>k.

Comment: @FabioSomenzi Yes but I mean to omit the equal so instead of <= it becomes only <. Is that valid? I am almost 100% sure but I have to convince someone.

Comment: Yes, no problem.  If $0 < f(n) \leq C g(n)$ for sufficiently large $n$, then $0 < f(n) < 2C g(n)$ too.